# How to create a Scene and a Stage using telegraf v4 in node js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, telegram, telegram-bot, telegraf.js

My problem is that there is not much information about making a Scene and Stage with Telegraf in node js, I mean Telegraf version 4.

I searched a bit on the internet and found some documentation, but all of them are for version 3, not for later versions. The only link that was better than the others was [this](https://github.com/telegraf/telegraf/issues/705) link. As I said, it is for the 3rd version of Telegraf.

If anyone knows anything about making and handling Stages and Scenes, I would be grateful if you could help me.

Answer (score 0):

Work with scenes
Example:

```
const weatherStage = new Scenes.Stage(scene)
```

or array

```
const weatherStage = new Scenes.Stage([scenes])
```